# minimize the UIImagePickerController view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i am working on a camera app. i want to restrict the image content in particular dimensions, but the image through camera is coming in full screen. How can i minimize it?

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    OvlayView *overlay = [[OvlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(472, 158, 240, 128)];

    // Create a new image picker instance:
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    // Set the image picker source:
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Hide the controls:
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // Make camera view full screen:
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);

    // Insert the overlay:
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    /*UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480,320));

    CGContextRef            context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

    UIImage        *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();*/
    // Show the picker:
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Comment: picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, 0.52412, 0.52412);

Comment: ya i tried this its not working!!!!